# RecursiveDirectoryIterator not working in admin

Tags: php

my function below works error free when viewing the frontend of the website. But causes a fatal error when i login to the admin area. The errors say that it can no longer find the folder.

```
//req all the php files in current & sub dirs.
function req_php_files($filepath) {
    $Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($filepath);
    $Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
    $Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

    $php_files = array();

    foreach ($Regex as $file) {
        array_push($php_files, $file[0]);
    }
    foreach ($php_files as $req_file) {
        require_once $req_file;
    }
}
req_php_files('wp-content/themes/vac3/acf');
```

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(wp-content/themes/vac3/acf): failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vac3/wp-content/themes/vac3/functions.php:177`

Why does this function work on the front end of the site but I'm not when I log into admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your **relative** path. When you visit the `/wp-admin/`, it will try to locate the `wp-content/themes/vac3/acf` within and it doesn't find it there. Try instead the full path with help of `__DIR__` or `get_template_directory()` – more details in this [blog post](http://wpkrauts.com/2015/the-guide-to-wordpress-path-and-urls/). What if you later remove the `acf/` subdirectory? You might want to check it's existence with `is_dir()`. Also you might want to use the [`FilesystemIterator` (the parent class) constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants) and use `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` to skip `.` and `..` pointers and `FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS` (PHP v5.3.1+) to … follow symlinks. You might also want to use `FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME` to avoid returning objects when you just need the *path* to files.

If you don't need this on the backend you could hook it to the front-end or use the `! is_admin()` check within your hook. You should also take care of only loading this where needed. I also wonder if this should be a plugin? Then there are alternatives like autoloading.

The normal thing to do is to wrap everything up in a callback attached to some filter or hook. Example:

```
// Use the proper filter – below just as example
add_filter( 'wp_loaded', function() {

    // Only serve for public requests
    if ( is_admin() )
        return;

    $Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( get_template_directory().'/acf' )
    );
    $Regex = new RegexIterator(
        $Iterator, 
        '/^.+\.php$/i', 
        RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH
    );

    foreach ( $Regex as $file )
        require_once $file[0];
} );
```

Even better would be if you just use the `FilesystemIterator` in case you only have a single folder to require files from – non recursively:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {

    if ( is_admin() )
        return;

    $files = new \FilesystemIterator( 
        get_template_directory().'/acf', 
        \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
        | FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
        | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME
    );

    foreach ( $files as $file )
    {
        /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
        ! $files->isDir() and include $files->getRealPath();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks @kaiser for extending the tiny answer ;-) Good working examples and shows how the predefined constants can be helpful. I wonder if we need `is_dir()` check on the `get_template_directory().'/acf'` path before feeding it into `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` or `FilesystemIterator`. ? I played with this recently and if I recall correctly this was need for non-existent directories, but that might be wrongly recalled  ;-)

Comment: np :) – Ad _directories_ ) The 2nd part is mostly explanatory and not meant to work. Why would one `FOLLOW_SYMLINKS`, but `! $files->is_dir()`? Doesn't make any sense and should only explain possibilities (mostly because recursive dir question). And yes, ignoring directories is indeed needed. Btw, you can check against `$files->getType()` as well and should get `file`/`link`/`dir` in return according to the docs. Of course, you can also set up the it to return [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) with `FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO` to make things real fun.

Comment: Even more interesting would be to use a custom class by extending [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.setfileclass.php) and make this more WordPress specific. One could then add stuff like current template hierarchy, query objects and what not alongside things. Or maybe add attachment DB info as sugar on top of just the file from _uploads_. Endless possibilities, that, depending on caching solutions, could stick in cache (and memory) and serve media lists very fast.

Comment: it looks like you have written a great answer in the comments as well ;-) yes that SplFileInfo approach sound exiting, ... thanks for all that info, will check out your link, just on my way to the kindergarten now ;-) @kaiser

Comment: np, maybe you can ask a new question when you are researching further and show what you find as follow up. And btw, I thought you are a bit older. Pretty impressive knowledge … for a 5-year old! :D

Comment: hahaha lol - let's see what happens ;-) Some days I feel like my WordPress  progress + understanding is that of a 5 year old, but then again I think most 5-year old kids nowadays have much better english knowledge than I will ever have ;-) @kaiser

Comment: Got an error as FilesystemIterator tried to load the .functions.php.swp